# How to return a blank page if there isn't an index page in the folder using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to return a blank page if there isn't an index page in the folder using htaccess

Take a look :
http://webdev.faressoft.org/wp-admin/images/

I do not want any one to see the names of these files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 " "
```

However, some browsers (Internet Explorer and Chrome) ignore short error pages.

Answer (score 4):

You could create an empty index page. There's a much better solution though:
Add `Options -Indexes` to your .htaccess file; that will result in a 403 error page instead of a directory listing.

If you really want a blank page you can add `ErrorDocument 403 " "` to your .htaccess (don't forget the space, an empty string won't work!)

Comment: Options -Indexes ! What do mean ?

Comment: That disables directory listing ("seeing the names of these files").

Comment: If you really want a blank page, I'd go for the empty index page.

Comment: That won't work for subdirs though.. so he should at least also disable indexes.. then subdirs will yield a 403 error instead of a dir listing.

Comment: That's right. He probably needs a real file in the ErrorDocument 403 directive with 4KB worth of spaces.

Comment: Only IE (6?) requires a certain error page length.. so a single space should be enough for every real browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make a defualt error page. if index page does'nt exist redirect to that error page. simply write this code in .htaccess file.

```
    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com/404.htm
```

404.htm is your own created error page.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is so wrong: There is a directory listing and no error if there's no index page. He needs to handle 403 and not 404. Redirecting on 404 is a bad thing as the URL in the location bar changes - that's why relative paths should be used in ErrorDocument directives.